# How can you use multiple directories for static files in blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to have access to two folders of my static files. One is `wwwroot`, and the other is `Uploads`, which is on the server.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

[image]

I have tested the following scenarios:

```cs
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
string rootpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
string rootpath2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(rootpath2),
    RequestPath = "/wwwroot"
});
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads")),
    RequestPath = "/Uploads"
});
```

However, I don't have access to the `wwwroot` directory. The only scenario where I can access `wwwroot` is when I write the following code:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

But in this case, I don't have access to the `Uploads` folder.

Comment: Normally you do not want to save files on a Server.  You do not want any hacker to resources on the server.  I would create a shared folder on the client machine and save files on the shared drive.  You have a HTTP connection with a client and server.  Uploads you would need to send the file across the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to give a user direct access to that folder.  Your code can access it, though.  Just use something like:

```
 string baseDir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
 string fullPath = baseDir + "uploads/" + filename;
  using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open))
  {
      await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
  }
  memory.Position = 0;
  return File(memory, mimetype, output_filename);
```

I put this at an endpoint that takes a file_id as a parameter then does a DB lookup for the file's path and name.