Create folder wwroot in ASP.NET Core Web API with a method code
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API for back of my web application, the front is Angular. I need to save things like images or PDF's in my server and access them, so I want to save these files in the wwwroot folder, to get a url that I can use to show them in the frontend.
The problem is that I want that wwwroot to be created when I try to save an image in my application (like a client) of save a file (image or PDF), I try to use Directory.Create, as you can see in the screenshots.
But this folder is created in the specific route but I can't see in my project or keep an image there
code
folder of the project
structure of the project
I want to create wwroot for my API and save documents there in my API for use in my web application.

the wwwroot is already created (though while debugging it's virtual...)  You can do something like: string FileRootPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");  However, you may not want to provide a direct URL path to the file.  It's better to write files outside of direct URL access... so maybe create a directory in AppContext.BaseDirectory, and then have your back end serve individual files (return File) when a certain endpoint is called and user access is verified.

also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093274/how-can-you-use-multiple-directories-for-static-files-in-blazor/78109290#78109290

Could you please include your actual code snippet in order to reproduce your scenario.

Further to Farid's request, please include code as unformatted text, rather than an image.
